# What is a screw head with a circle and 3 lines called?

Tags: ford, tools, old-cars, bumper, screw

I have a 16 year old Ford Ikon car and that got a kind of weird screws all over (mainly at the bumber). Attached the image for reference. What is this type of screw is called? I don't find any screw driver to unscrew this. Need help.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's a screw?  It doesn't look like one to me.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! That looks like a plastic push pin holder thingy ... What is it attached to? Can you see the back side at all?

Comment: Possibly a pop-rivet.; rivet from one side with no access to the backside.

Comment: @jwh20 possible you are right. I tried with a normal screw driver and it only rotates but not coming out. Also it is not plastic and it is steel. How can I remove that. It is joining car bumper to steel (plastic with Steel)

Comment: What's on the back side?